# Is Bot analytics in Azure working for conversations through Skype for Business?

Tags: botframework, skype-for-business

I have bots working with the Bot Framework v3 and v4 through Web, Skype for Business, MS Teams and Slack.
In the Azure Portal, in the Bot service I go to analytics and see usage data but not for Skype for Business. Is there a problem with that channel? Is there something that has to be done in order to enable it?
I didn't see any mention about that in the documentation, and interestingly enough the example screenshot contains a lot of channels but not Skype for business, odd being a Microsoft documentation.

Comment: Same thing is happening with BotFramework v4

Comment: Could you open up an [issue on botbuilder](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/new) to track this, since it appears to be an ongoing issue?